# Null is returned from a method that is expected to return non-null value (UITableViewCell)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I am just, 
1) Dequeueing the cell
2) Checking nil
3) setting cell data as per situation 
and returning the cell.

What is wrong with this code? What am i doing wrong? Simply checking `nil`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
GSDischargeListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    [tableView registerClass:[GSDischargeListCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

if (_searchController.active && ![_searchController.searchBar.text  isEqual: @""] ) {
    GSDischargePatient *patient = searchResultsArray[indexPath.row];
    [cell setCellData:patient];
} else {
    GSDischargePatient *patient = datasourceArray[indexPath.row];
    [cell setCellData:patient];
}
   _totalHeight = [cell estimatedHeightOfCell];

   return cell;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all never register cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Register your cell (once) in `viewDidLoad` if necessary at all.

The error occurs because you are only **registering** a cell but not **creating** one if `cell` is `nil.`

A more convenient way is to use the other `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method (`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`) which returns always a non-null valid cell. A check for `nil` is not needed. Further cast the cell to the subclass.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     GSDischargeListCell *cell = (GSDischargeListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];

     if (_searchController.active && ... 
}
```